# creating a modified graphhopper instance with updated edge weights

Tags: maven, graph, maps, graphhopper

How can I create multiple graphs each with their own set of edge weights? For example, NY area with edge weights at 12AM, 6AM, 12PM, etc.

How can I update a graph with changes and save my changes to be loaded later. Is this possible? Or is there another approach? My direction was to edit the weighting [code](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/weighting.md) on the github under the core docs. To use a previous S/O [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132484/does-graphhopper-support-dynamic-edge-weights), regarding dynamic edge weights. Where does this code get placed?

Also, brand new to this project and have not used a project environment as such (maven?). Can someone give me some pointers on how to use the MyGraphhopper extended class with overridding methods? What environment would I need to install on OSX to see the similar core or web interface?

If the above is not possible via web interface, how could I run queries using the command line?

Thanks,

Comment: You'll have probably a hard to to implement such a feature if you do not know Java or Maven at all. On OS X the installation is similar to linux and already explained in the docs. Maybe you take a bit time to learn Java and then try again - ie learning step by step :)